# Make theme editor to show all theme's files

Tags: theme-development, directory

Is there a way to make all files (also in subfolder) in my theme directory visible in the theme editor? I need a way to edit themes without having to upload a new one every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is not possible in the current version, is a old ticket in the trac.
But you can add a other editor via plugin and it works, like [WPide](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpide/)

Comment: There is also the [Advanced Code Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-code-editor) plugin.